# How to filter JSON Data in JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to filter JSON data using Javascript or jQuery?

This my JSON data:

```
[{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A4298","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A2222","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41Awww33","website":"yahoo"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A424448","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429rr8","website":"ebay"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ff8","website":"ebay"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ss8","website":"rediff"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429sg8","website":"yahoo"}]
```

JavaScript:

```
obj1 = JSON.parse(jsondata);
```

now I only want name and website data which is contain website is equal to **"yahoo"**

Comment: @RoyiNamir check now ....

Comment: Fairly trivial. Use [jQuery.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/).

Comment: @SalmanA I dont know anything about GREP..can you tell me how can use GREP in above example

Answer (score 87, accepted):

This is how you should do it : ( for google find)

```
$([
  {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A4298","website":"google222"},
  {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A2222","website":"google"}
  ])
    .filter(function (i,n){
        return n.website==='google';
    });
```

**Better** solution :  ( Salman's)

```
$.grep( [{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A4298","website":"google"},{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A2222","website":"google"}], function( n, i ) {
  return n.website==='google';
});
```

http://jsbin.com/yakubixi/4/edit

Comment: Returning values from `.each` will **not** work (false can be returned to terminate the loop but that is about it).

Comment: @RoyiNamir var as=$(temp).filter(function (i,n){return n.website==='Google'});alert(as);

Comment: @Me7888 Yes. that's correct. assume json is an object. ( not its string representation).

Comment: @RoyiNamir HI..... possible to get two website list like : return n.website==='Google' || n.website==='Yahoo'

Comment: @Me7888 Are you asking or saying ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir asking ...how can possible if I want two website list

Answer (score 41):

No need for jQuery unless you target old browsers and don't want to use shims.

```
var yahooOnly = JSON.parse(jsondata).filter(function (entry) {
    return entry.website === 'yahoo';
});
```

In ES2015:

```
const yahooOnly = JSON.parse(jsondata).filter(({website}) => website === 'yahoo');
```

Comment: filter is not widely support ( as you mentioned)

Comment: @RoyiNamir Please read the beginning of my answer. And by the way: http://caniuse.com/#search=filter

Comment: Ok then. ( im not the downvoter:-)) p.s. why the link ?  I already know that it is not supported widely in older Ie's

Comment: I would argue that it, in fact, **is** widely supported (older IEs run on XP which is discontinued anyway). Hence the link. Besides, including a shim is much better than including the entire jQuery.

Comment: Oleg  : me— as a webdeveloper can't allow this to happen ( not support ie9.) sorry

Comment: Gosh... nobody says that you shouldn't support IE9. My point is that from the maintainability perspective, it's best to code for standards and provide the necessary shims with IE conditional comments.

Comment: Adding a shim for `filter` while you can do it with  pure [jQ filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function (which he already has on page) - is a reduandant thing to do.( IMO)

Comment: He never says that he has jQuery on page already. The question is JavaScript **or** jQuery. And jQuery in itself is redundant anyway.

Comment: jquery is redundant ? ok. let's move on.

Comment: JSON.parse(...).filter is not a function

Answer (score 40):

The following code works for me:

```js
var data = [{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A4298","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A2222","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41Awww33","website":"yahoo"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A424448","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429rr8","website":"ebay"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ff8","website":"ebay"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ss8","website":"rediff"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429sg8","website":"yahoo"}]

var data_filter = data.filter( element => element.website =="yahoo")
console.log(data_filter)
```

Comment: This code doesn't filter data by "yahoo". It change all of them to "yahoo". The question is how to get data where  website is equal to "yahoo".

Comment: @probitaille Thanks for the heads up. I corrected the code.

Comment: It's works as expected now. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 22):

Try this way, allow you even filter by other key

data:

```
var my_data = [{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A4298","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A2222","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41Awww33","website":"yahoo"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A424448","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429rr8","website":"ebay"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ff8","website":"ebay"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ss8","website":"rediff"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429sg8","website":"yahoo"}];
```

usage:

```
//We do that to ensure to get a correct JSON
var my_json = JSON.stringify(my_data)
//We can use {'name': 'Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ff8'} as criteria too
var filtered_json = find_in_object(JSON.parse(my_json), {website: 'yahoo'});
```

filter function

```
function find_in_object(my_object, my_criteria){

  return my_object.filter(function(obj) {
    return Object.keys(my_criteria).every(function(c) {
      return obj[c] == my_criteria[c];
    });
  });

}
```

Comment: Great Work,
What if i want to pass 2 or more filter in this line:
"var filtered_json = find_in_object(JSON.parse(my_json), {website: 'yahoo'});"

Answer (score 4):

You can use **jQuery each function** as it is explained below:

**Define your data:**

```
var jsonStr = '[{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A4298,"website":"google"},{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A2222,"website":"google"},{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41Awww33,"website":"yahoo"},{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A424448,"website":"google"},{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429rr8,"website":"ebay"},{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ff8,"website":"ebay"},{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ss8,"website":"rediff"},{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429sg8,"website":"yahoo"}]';
```

**Parse JSON string to JSON object:**

```
var json = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
```

**Iterate and filter:**

```
$.each(JSON.parse(json), function (idx, obj) {
    if (obj.website == 'yahoo') {
        // do whatever you want
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The values can be retrieved during the parsing:

```js
var yahoo = [], j = `[{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A4298","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A2222","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41Awww33","website":"yahoo"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A424448","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429rr8","website":"ebay"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ff8","website":"ebay"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ss8","website":"rediff"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429sg8","website":"yahoo"}]`

var data = JSON.parse(j, function(key, value) { 
      if ( value.website === "yahoo" ) yahoo.push(value); 
      return value; })

console.log( yahoo )
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the question explicitly says JS or jQuery, but anyway using
**lodash** is always on the table for other searchers I suppose.

From the source [docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter):

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'active': false }
];

_.filter(users, function(o) { return !o.active; });
// => objects for ['fred']

// The `_.matches` iteratee shorthand.
_.filter(users, { 'age': 36, 'active': true });
// => objects for ['barney']

// The `_.matchesProperty` iteratee shorthand.
_.filter(users, ['active', false]);
// => objects for ['fred']

// The `_.property` iteratee shorthand.
_.filter(users, 'active');
// => objects for ['barney']
```

So the solution for the original question would be just one liner:

```
var result = _.filter(data, ['website', 'yahoo']);
```

Answer (score 0):

It iterates through the json objects, and searches each value you are concerned about, 'website', and if it equals "yahoo" you can then return that value or do whatever you like there. Right now it just logs that element to the console.

```
jsonObj.forEach(function (element, index) {
    if(element['website'] === 'yahoo'){
        console.log('found', element)   
    }
})
```