# Filtering data with jQuery.grep()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to filter data stored in a .js. I tried jQuery.grep() method* but every data are still loading.

Data

```
var myData = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": {"name": urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"},
"features": [    
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 11, "type": "capitale", "pays": "pas fr", "nom": "berlin" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 13.395132552297285, 52.508943107353431 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 10, "type": "capitale", "pays": "pas fr", "nom": "amsterdam" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 4.855651367625091, 52.394023028252583 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 9, "type": "capitale", "pays": "pas fr", "nom": "londres" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -0.141426738862896, 51.509964983366203 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 8, "type": "capitale", "pays": "pas fr", "nom": "bruxelles" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 4.323617445236209, 50.851394650375276 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 7, "type": "ville", "pays": "france", "nom": "dijon" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 5.050954959388099, 47.311364936576716 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 6, "type": "ville", "pays": "france", "nom": "clermont-ferrand" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 3.13832668143313, 45.876878693687296 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 5, "type": "ville", "pays": "france", "nom": "lyon" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 4.848916761012574, 45.7642371486427 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 4, "type": "capitale", "pays": "france", "nom": "paris" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 2.316704674705995, 48.867681379583189 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 3, "type": "ville", "pays": "france", "nom": "montpellier" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 3.91954104848516, 43.619755259636626 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 2, "type": "ville", "pays": "france", "nom": "toulouse" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1.414267388628651, 43.600250453043067 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": 1, "type": "ville", "pays": "france", "nom": "rennes" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -1.670182439904363, 48.153851807885481 ] } }
]
};
```

Function

```
var myFilter = $.grep(myData.features, function (element, index) {
            return element.properties.pays == "france";
        });

        for (var i=0;i<myFilter.length;i++) {
            alert(myFilter[0].properties.pays + "  " + myFilter[0].properties.nom);
        };
```

Something is wrong with this syntax, but i don't see where.

- [How to filter JSON Data in JavaScript or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720988/how-to-filter-json-data-in-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: Do you see error in browser console?

Comment: Yes :ReferenceError: myFilter is not defined

for (var i=0;i<myFilter.length;i++) {

Comment: The method signature `jQuery.grep( array, function [, invert ] )` seems to suggest that `$.grep()` is meant for arrays, not objects.

Comment: Exact, `.filter()` would it be more appropriate ?

Answer (score 0):

`element` does not have a field `pays`. You need to use `element.properties`:

```
var myFilter = $.grep(myData.features, function (element, index) {
    return element.properties.pays == "france";
});
```

Comment: Correct, sorry for the mistake. But all my data is still loading.

Comment: If you are saying that the code in your question does not match the code you are using then you need to edit your question. Nobody can help you if they cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: I'm also not sure I understand when you say "my data is still loading". What exactly does that mean?

Comment: Sorry, i want to say that the result is the same. But as @PeterKA says `jQuery.grep` is meant for arrays, not objects... logic.

Comment: ...yes, `jQuery.grep` is meant for arrays. Maybe @PeterKA didn't notice this, but your `myData.features` *is* an array.

Comment: That's what I thought at the beginning, but then how to explain that this does not work ? Nothing seems to be wrong in the syntax.

Comment: That is why I claim that what you have in your question does not match what you are actually using. For me (after fixing a couple of typos in your `myData` object, and using your corrected code) this does work.

Comment: I have fixed typos and corrected my code and it works. The alert message also need to be fixed `alert(myFilter[0].properties.pays + " " + myFilter[0].properties.nom);`