# Query a nested JSON Object/Array with underscore

Tags: json, filter, underscore.js, where-clause, querying

Assumed that is the JSON structure:

```
var myData = [
  {
    "id": 68,
    "country": "US",
  },
  {
    "id": 82,
    "country": "PL",
  },
  {
    "id": 83,
    "country": "US",
  }
];
```

I want to get all items, where country == US

Following try does not work:

```
var myResult = _.where (myData, {'country': 'US'});
```

I get an empty result > `myResult []`

What is the mistake?

**EDIT: Sorry, the use of lodash and underscore together was the problem !**

Comment: Take a look at this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720988/how-to-filter-json-data-in-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: I am looking for a underscore solution, other libraries are out of the scope,..

Comment: Can you use a native ES5 JavaScript solution (`filter`)?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code posted in the OP, see this: https://jsfiddle.net/cyqzan1a/. Something else is wrong here. Post more code.

Comment: The only thing that may be wrong here is that the OP is actually using the latest version of lodash (v4.3.0) which is sometimes confused with underscore. `_.where` does not exists in that version of lodash, but does in previous versions.

Comment: @Vienna are you sure you are using underscore, or is it possible you are using lodash instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used `underscore.js` before, but I have tried your code and it works totally.

Please make sure that you are importing the library.

I have used the next code in the `body` tag of an empty HTML file:

```
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script>
    var myData = [
      {
        "id": 68,
        "country": "US",
      },
      {
        "id": 82,
        "country": "PL",
      },
      {
        "id": 83,
        "country": "US",
      }
    ];

    var myResult = _.where (myData, {'country': 'US'});
    console.log(myResult);
</script>
```

And the result is:

[image: Console result]