# Filtering array with specific values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this JSON:

```
{
  "1": {
    "PerId":"10900662",
    "Name":"Cueball",
    "Email":"cueb@example.com",
    "DepartId":"11"
  },
  "2": {
    "PerId":"10900664",
    "Name":"Megan",
    "MuEmail":"megan@example.com",
    "DepartId":"11"
  },
  "3": {
    "PerId":"10900665",
    "Name":"Beret Guy",
    "MuEmail":"bg@example.com",
    "DepartId":"12"
  }
}
```

Which I want to filter with a specific `DepartId`

Here's the code I've tested, which is from [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720988/how-to-filter-json-data-in-javascript-or-jquery):

```
<html>
<body>
  Test!
</body>
<script>
  var y = JSON.parse('{"1":{"PerId":"10900662","Name":"Cueball","Email":"cueb@example.com","DepartId":"11"},"2": {"PerId":"10900664","Name":"Megan","MuEmail":"megan@example.com","DepartId":"11"},"3": {"PerId":"10900665","Name":"Beret Guy","MuEmail":"bg@example.com","DepartId":"12"}}');
  var z = y.filter(function (i,n){return n.DepartId == '11'})
</script>
</html>
```

In this case, y returns an object, but Firefox throws error that `y.filter is not a function.`

I expected y to return as something like

```
{
  "1": {
    "PerId":"10900662",
    "Name":"Cueball",
    "Email":"cueb@example.com",
    "DepartId":"11"
  },
  "2": {
    "PerId":"10900664",
    "Name":"Megan",
    "MuEmail":"megan@example.com",
    "DepartId":"11"
  }
}
```

in the form of JavaScript object. How do I make it work?

Comment: `filter()` can be applied for array not object

Comment: What you got is an object. Filter only work with arrays, it should be `[
  {
    "PerId":"10900662",
    "Name":"Cueball",
    "Email":"cueb@example.com",
    "DepartId":"11"
  },
   {
    "PerId":"10900664",
    "Name":"Megan",
    "MuEmail":"megan@example.com",
    "DepartId":"11"
  }
];`

Answer (score 1):

[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is defined on the `Array` prototype. It cannot be used on object.

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get all the keys in the object and `for` loop to iterate over them.

```
// Get all keys from the `obj`
var keys = Object.keys(obj),
    result = {};


// Iterate over all properties in obj
for (var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++) {
    // If the ID is to be filtered
    if (obj[keys[i]].DepartId === '11') {

        // Add the object in the result object
        result[keys[i]] = obj[keys[i]];
    }
}
```

```js
var obj = {
    "1": {
        "PerId": "10900662",
        "Name": "Cueball",
        "Email": "cueb@example.com",
        "DepartId": "11"
    },
    "2": {
        "PerId": "10900664",
        "Name": "Megan",
        "MuEmail": "megan@example.com",
        "DepartId": "11"
    },
    "3": {
        "PerId": "10900665",
        "Name": "Beret Guy",
        "MuEmail": "bg@example.com",
        "DepartId": "12"
    }
};

var keys = Object.keys(obj),
    result = {};

for (var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (obj[keys[i]].DepartId === '11') {
        result[keys[i]] = obj[keys[i]];
    }
}

console.log(result);
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4);
```

---

I'll recommend to change the data format to use array of objects. Then `filter()` can be directly applied on array.

```
var arr = [{
    "PerId": "10900662",
    "Name": "Cueball",
    "Email": "cueb@example.com",
    "DepartId": "11"
}, {
    "PerId": "10900664",
    "Name": "Megan",
    "MuEmail": "megan@example.com",
    "DepartId": "11"
}, {
    "PerId": "10900665",
    "Name": "Beret Guy",
    "MuEmail": "bg@example.com",
    "DepartId": "12"
}];

var result = arr.filter(obj => obj.DepartId === '11');
console.log(result);
```

```js
var arr = [{
    "PerId": "10900662",
    "Name": "Cueball",
    "Email": "cueb@example.com",
    "DepartId": "11"
}, {
    "PerId": "10900664",
    "Name": "Megan",
    "MuEmail": "megan@example.com",
    "DepartId": "11"
}, {
    "PerId": "10900665",
    "Name": "Beret Guy",
    "MuEmail": "bg@example.com",
    "DepartId": "12"
}];

var result = arr.filter(obj => obj.DepartId === '11');

console.log(result);
document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use an array filter on an object. Look over the example again.

```
$([ // this is an array of objects
    {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A4298","website":"google222"},
    {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A2222","website":"google"}
  ])
    .filter(function (i,n){
        return n.website==='google';
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter` is prototype of array function not `object`,so we can not use here.

To achieve output, we can use `for-in` loop on `object`

```
var y = JSON.parse('{"1":{"PerId":"10900662","Name":"Cueball","Email":"cueb@example.com","DepartId":"11"},"2": {"PerId":"10900664","Name":"Megan","MuEmail":"megan@example.com","DepartId":"11"},"3": {"PerId":"10900665","Name":"Beret Guy","MuEmail":"bg@example.com","DepartId":"12"}}');

var res = {}
for(var key in y){
  if(y[key].DepartId === '11')
   res[key] = y[key]
}
console.log(res)
```