# Filter JSON by key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, filter

I have the following JSON and I want to keep the array in the same format but only include objects with type `"ar"`.  How can I filter this JSON with JavaScript to only include the types I need?

```
[{"time":"2016-07-26 09:02:27","type":"aa"},
{"time":"2016-04-21 20:35:07","type":"ae"},
{"time":"2016-08-20 03:31:57","type":"ar"},
{"time":"2017-01-19 22:58:06","type":"ae"},
{"time":"2016-08-28 10:19:27","type":"ae"},
{"time":"2016-12-06 10:36:22","type":"ar"},
{"time":"2016-07-09 12:14:03","type":"ar"},
{"time":"2016-10-25 05:05:37","type":"ae"},
{"time":"2016-06-05 07:57:18","type":"ae"},
{"time":"2016-10-08 22:03:03","type":"aa"},
{"time":"2016-08-13 21:27:37","type":"ae"},
{"time":"2016-04-09 07:36:16","type":"ar"},
{"time":"2016-12-30 17:20:08","type":"aa"},
{"time":"2016-03-11 17:31:46","type":"aa"},
{"time":"2016-05-04 14:08:25","type":"ar"},
{"time":"2016-11-29 05:21:02","type":"ar"},
{"time":"2016-03-08 05:46:01","type":"ar"},
]
```

Comment: Important technical distinction: *JSON is a string* (it is a way to serialize JavaScript data structure as string data, nothing more). The only thing you can do with it is either perform string operations, or *parse* it into JavaScript data structures. What you are asking about is filtering an array of objects, based on some key used by those objects; you are **not** asking about filtering JSON.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter JSON Data in JavaScript or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720988/how-to-filter-json-data-in-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You should use `filter` method.

The `filter()` method creates a new `array` with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

**Provided** function is a `callback` which is applied to each element of the array.

```js
var arr = [{"time":"2016-07-26 09:02:27","type":"aa"}, {"time":"2016-04-21 20:35:07","type":"ae"}, {"time":"2016-08-20 03:31:57","type":"ar"}, {"time":"2017-01-19 22:58:06","type":"ae"}, {"time":"2016-08-28 10:19:27","type":"ae"}, {"time":"2016-12-06 10:36:22","type":"ar"}, {"time":"2016-07-09 12:14:03","type":"ar"}, {"time":"2016-10-25 05:05:37","type":"ae"}, {"time":"2016-06-05 07:57:18","type":"ae"}, {"time":"2016-10-08 22:03:03","type":"aa"}, {"time":"2016-08-13 21:27:37","type":"ae"}, {"time":"2016-04-09 07:36:16","type":"ar"}, {"time":"2016-12-30 17:20:08","type":"aa"}, {"time":"2016-03-11 17:31:46","type":"aa"}, {"time":"2016-05-04 14:08:25","type":"ar"}, {"time":"2016-11-29 05:21:02","type":"ar"}, {"time":"2016-03-08 05:46:01","type":"ar"}, ];

console.log(arr.filter(function(item){
    return item.type == "ar";         
}));
```

Also, you can use a `shorter` way with `arrow` *functions*:

```
var filtered = arr.filter(a => a.type == "ar");
```

Comment: If I have to filter out based on type as well as latest timestamp, can you please suggest as to how can it be done?

Comment: @iOS_programmer, do you need to filter by two fields ?

Comment: Yes.. for example in the above json... I would want the type ''ar" which has the latest timestamp.. It would be really appreciated if you can let me know how to filter latest timestamp along with type.

Comment: Thank you, saved my time

Answer (score 4):

Using `filter` method you can filter the array to return only those elements which match a particular condition `data.filter((x)=>x.type === "ar");`

The `filter` method creates a new array with all elements that will pass the condition  `x.type === "ar"`

```js
var data =[{"time":"2016-07-26 09:02:27","type":"aa"},
{"time":"2016-04-21 20:35:07","type":"ae"},
{"time":"2016-08-20 03:31:57","type":"ar"},
{"time":"2017-01-19 22:58:06","type":"ae"},
{"time":"2016-08-28 10:19:27","type":"ae"},
{"time":"2016-12-06 10:36:22","type":"ar"},
{"time":"2016-07-09 12:14:03","type":"ar"},
{"time":"2016-10-25 05:05:37","type":"ae"},
{"time":"2016-06-05 07:57:18","type":"ae"},
{"time":"2016-10-08 22:03:03","type":"aa"},
{"time":"2016-08-13 21:27:37","type":"ae"},
{"time":"2016-04-09 07:36:16","type":"ar"},
{"time":"2016-12-30 17:20:08","type":"aa"},
{"time":"2016-03-11 17:31:46","type":"aa"},
{"time":"2016-05-04 14:08:25","type":"ar"},
{"time":"2016-11-29 05:21:02","type":"ar"},
{"time":"2016-03-08 05:46:01","type":"ar"},
];
           
var result = data.filter((x)=>x.type === "ar");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `filter` function. Check [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Browser_compatibility) first:

```
var result = a.filter(function(v){
    return v.type==='ar';
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
var list = [
  {"time":"2016-07-26 09:02:27","type":"aa"},
  {"time":"2016-04-21 20:35:07","type":"ae"},
  {"time":"2016-08-20 03:31:57","type":"ar"},
  {"time":"2017-01-19 22:58:06","type":"ae"},
  {"time":"2016-08-28 10:19:27","type":"ae"},
  {"time":"2016-12-06 10:36:22","type":"ar"},
  {"time":"2016-07-09 12:14:03","type":"ar"},
  {"time":"2016-10-25 05:05:37","type":"ae"},
  {"time":"2016-06-05 07:57:18","type":"ae"},
  {"time":"2016-10-08 22:03:03","type":"aa"},
  {"time":"2016-08-13 21:27:37","type":"ae"},
  {"time":"2016-04-09 07:36:16","type":"ar"},
  {"time":"2016-12-30 17:20:08","type":"aa"},
  {"time":"2016-03-11 17:31:46","type":"aa"},
  {"time":"2016-05-04 14:08:25","type":"ar"},
  {"time":"2016-11-29 05:21:02","type":"ar"},
  {"time":"2016-03-08 05:4601","type":"ar"},
];

var result = list.filter(function(obj, index){
  return obj.type==='ar';
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as clean as the answer above, but will still do the job

```
var list = [{"time":"2016-07-26 09:02:27","type":"aa"},
{"time":"2016-04-21 20:35:07","type":"ae"},
{"time":"2016-08-20 03:31:57","type":"ar"},
{"time":"2017-01-19 22:58:06","type":"ae"},
{"time":"2016-08-28 10:19:27","type":"ae"},
{"time":"2016-12-06 10:36:22","type":"ar"},
{"time":"2016-07-09 12:14:03","type":"ar"},
{"time":"2016-10-25 05:05:37","type":"ae"},
{"time":"2016-06-05 07:57:18","type":"ae"},
{"time":"2016-10-08 22:03:03","type":"aa"},
{"time":"2016-08-13 21:27:37","type":"ae"},
{"time":"2016-04-09 07:36:16","type":"ar"},
{"time":"2016-12-30 17:20:08","type":"aa"},
{"time":"2016-03-11 17:31:46","type":"aa"},
{"time":"2016-05-04 14:08:25","type":"ar"},
{"time":"2016-11-29 05:21:02","type":"ar"},
{"time":"2016-03-08 05:46:01","type":"ar"},
]

var newList = [];

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i].type === 'ar') {
        newList.push(list[i]);
    }
}

console.log(newList);
```