# JavaScript: How to filter a JSON array if the key contains special characters?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON response that looks like this:

```json
[
    {
        "@level": "info",
        "@message": "Text"
    },
    {
        "@level": "error",
        "@message": "Text"
    },
    {
        "@level": "info",
        "@message": "Text"
    }
]
```

How can I filter the JSON response to only show Objects where `"@level" === "error"`. I am aware how to generally filter JSON arrays in JS ([e.g. as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42143031/filter-json-by-key-value)). However, this solution does not work if the key contains a special character like `@`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: [Use bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors): `obj['@level']` not `obj.@level`.

Comment: Oh man... sometimes it's too easy. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works the same as in your linked answer, just use bracket notaion on the array:

```js
let arr = [
    {
        "@level": "info",
        "@message": "Text"
    },
    {
        "@level": "error",
        "@message": "Text"
    },
    {
        "@level": "info",
        "@message": "Text"
    },
];

console.log(arr.filter(function(item){
    return item["@level"] == "error";
}));
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions where their duplicates [can be easily found](https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=javascript+key+special+characters&cat=web&pl=ext-ff&language=english&extVersion=1.3.0). Just close them as such.