# How to filter JSON object depends upon key name in angular 2?

Tags: json, angular, html-table

[image]

In my angular 2 application Headers are dynamically setting up. I arranged my JSON data as shown in attached image. I want to filter entire data using the Table Heading as a search term (Ex: Name or Position or Extn).

I am separating my result data to keys and values like:

```
this.keys= Object.keys(this.ResultData_search[0])` // my table heading false here
in my template :
<table>
<tr>
<th *ngFor=" let key of keys,let i=index"></th>
</tr>
<tr *ngFor=" let res of ResultData_search  ,let i = index" style="height: 35px;">
                        <td>{{i+1}}</td>
                        <td *ngFor=" let key of keys ">
                            {{res[key]}}
                        </td>


                    </tr>

</table
```

Why I am doing this is because my JSON data is not static. I have to set table headings and data dynamically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter JSON Data in JavaScript or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720988/how-to-filter-json-data-in-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: I made the following [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YVBJBX) to explain it

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a Pipe with an Array parameter containing the filters for each header.
In the Pipe you can dynamically filter your data for each header.

Let's assume you have the following component with a similar data structure as yours.  It has a filters Array of type IFilter  :

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-filter',
  templateUrl: './filter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filter.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class FilterComponent implements OnInit {

  data: Array<Map<string, string>>;
  headers: Array<string>;
  filters: Array<Ifilter>;
  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.data = new Array(
      new Map([["header1", "value11"], ["header2", "value12"], ["header3", "value13"], ["header4", "value14"], ["header5", "value15"]]),
      new Map([["header1", "value21"], ["header2", "value22"], ["header3", "value23"], ["header4", "value24"], ["header5", "value25"]]),
      new Map([["header1", "value31"], ["header2", "value32"], ["header3", "value33"], ["header4", "value34"], ["header5", "value35"]])
    );
    this.headers = Array.from((this.data[0]).keys());
    this.filters = new Array({header:"header1",filter:""},{header:"header2",filter:""},{header:"header3",filter:""},{header:"header4",filter:""},{header:"header5",filter:""})

  }

}
 export interface Ifilter{
    header : string;
    filter : string;
  }
```

Then define the following Pipe and filter for each header.

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { Ifilter } from "app/filter/filter.component";

@Pipe({
  name: 'pipeFilter',
  pure: false
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(data: Array<Map<string, string>>, filters: Array<Ifilter>): Array<Map<string, string>> {
    let filteredData = Array<Map<string, string>>();
    for (let row of data) {
      let exclude: boolean = false;
      for (let filter of filters) {
        if (filter.filter != '' && row.get(filter.header).indexOf(filter.filter) == -1) {
          exclude = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (!exclude)
        filteredData.push(row);

    }
    return filteredData;
  }
}
```

Finally, display the table with this template.
Get the filters with a two-way binding `[(NgModel)]` and pass them as parameter to the Pipe on the *ngFor : `*ngFor="let rows of data | pipeFilter:filters"`.   :

```js
  <table *ngIf="data && data.length">
    <th *ngFor="let header of headers">
      {{header}}
    </th>
    <tr>
      <td *ngFor="let filter of filters;let i=index">

       <input  type='text' [(ngModel)]='(filters[i]).filter' />

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let rows of data | pipeFilter:filters">
      <td *ngFor="let header of headers ">
        {{rows.get(header)}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Both Template and Pipe are completely dynamic and can handle any header.

Regard,
Philippe