# JavaScript - Returning index of an array based on matching property from another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I am trying to grab properties from an array of objects based on a matching title passed to an API call. I have the following two objects:

The first object is a simple title:

```
{
    "title": "Demo Import - Successful"
}
```

The second object is an array containing the above field and additional information:

```
"data": [{
        "columns": [
            "_source"
        ],
        "sort": [
            "example-timestamp",
            "asc"
        ],
        "title": "Demo Import - Authorization Failure"
    },
    {
        "columns": [
            "m-Form",
            "_type",
            "m-Identity"
        ],
        "sort": [
            "_type",
            "asc"
        ],
        "title": "Demo Import - Timed Out"
    },
    {
        "columns": [
            "_source"
        ],
        "sort": [
            "example-timestamp",
            "asc"
        ],
        "title": "Demo Import - Successful"
    }
]
```

I am currently trying to figure out how to find the matching property between the two objects, and then grab the rest of the information associated to that title in the following from:

```
{
    "title": "Demo Import - Successful",
    "sort": "example-timestamp",
    "direction": "asc",
    "columns": [_source]
}
```

Could someone provide me with a bit of guidance? I am still pretty new to working with objects in JavaScript. My current idea is to loop through data, and check each index for a matching title property. If there is a match, store the columns and title property, and then manipulate the sort properties into the form of

```
{
    "title": data.index.title,
    "sort": data.index.sort[0],
    "direction": data.index.sort[1],
    "columns": data.index.columns
}
```

Here is my current attempt that I can't quite get to work:

```
var match_title = {
    "title": "Demo Import - Successful"
};

var objects =
    "data": [{
            "columns": [
                "_source"
            ],
            "sort": [
                "example-timestamp",
                "asc"
            ],
            "title": "Demo Import - Authorization Failure"
        },
        {
            "columns": [
                "m-Form",
                "_type",
                "m-Identity"
            ],
            "sort": [
                "_type",
                "asc"
            ],
            "title": "Demo Import - Timed Out"
        },
        {
            "columns": [
                "_source"
            ],
            "sort": [
                "example-timestamp",
                "asc"
            ],
            "title": "Demo Import - Successful"
        }
    ];

function getObjects(name, data) {
    for (var i = 0, i < data.length, i++) {
        if (name.title == data[i].title) {
            var response = {
                "title": data[i].title,
                "sort": data[i].sort[0],
                "direction": data[i].sort[1],
                "columns": data[i].columns
            }
            return response;
        };
    };
};

var matchedObject = getObjects(match_title, objects);
```

Thank you in advance for you help.

**EDIT: Solved. Thank you everyone for the quick answers and great explanations!**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter JSON Data in JavaScript or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720988/how-to-filter-json-data-in-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: So, you want a new property called `direction` to be created with a value that is equal to the second item in the `sort` array property?

Comment: Simplest solution is a for-loop.

Comment: getObjects(match_title, objects.data);

Comment: @ScottMarucs yeah. I'm trying to programatically match elasticsearch saved search objects to their actual query, and the elasticsearch query takes a direction and a sort parameter, where the the saved search objects combine the two into a single sort object. Got it now!

Comment: See my answer below for a *much* simpler approach.

Comment: @BanksySan Simplest solution is `Array.filter` and no explicit loops.

Comment: @ScottMarcus True if the OP wanted to get an array of all matching elements.  It looks like a single object is required though, so I'd still say the most intuitive would be a loop with a break.

Comment: @BanksySan Could be. I interpreted the question as there only being one match in the target array.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Aye. The filter would parse the entire array which might be an issue for a very large array (unless it accepts a max number argument?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a combination of [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var match_title = {
  "title": "Demo Import - Successful"
};

var objects = {
  "data": [{
      "columns": [
        "_source"
      ],
      "sort": [
        "example-timestamp",
        "asc"
      ],
      "title": "Demo Import - Authorization Failure"
    },
    {
      "columns": [
        "m-Form",
        "_type",
        "m-Identity"
      ],
      "sort": [
        "_type",
        "asc"
      ],
      "title": "Demo Import - Timed Out"
    },
    {
      "columns": [
        "_source"
      ],
      "sort": [
        "example-timestamp",
        "asc"
      ],
      "title": "Demo Import - Successful"
    }
  ]
};

function getObjects(name, data) {
  return data.filter(function(d) {
    return name.title == d.title;
  }).map(function(d) {
    return {
      "title": d.title,
      "sort": d.sort[0],
      "direction": d.sort[1],
      "columns": d.columns
    }
  });
};

var matchedObject = getObjects(match_title, objects.data);
console.log(matchedObject)
```

Comment: If I use this method, how do I access the properties of matchedObject? 
I am trying to call matchedObject.title, but it comes back undefined.

Comment: This returns an array. So if you had multiple matching objects, you'll get all of them. So, for your particular example, you can use `matchedObject[0]`

Answer (score 1):

your `objects` is not valid, then a lot error in your code, here the fix

```js
var match_title = {
  "title": "Demo Import - Successful"
};

var objects = {
  "data": [{
      "columns": [
        "_source"
      ],
      "sort": [
        "example-timestamp",
        "asc"
      ],
      "title": "Demo Import - Authorization Failure"
    },
    {
      "columns": [
        "m-Form",
        "_type",
        "m-Identity"
      ],
      "sort": [
        "_type",
        "asc"
      ],
      "title": "Demo Import - Timed Out"
    },
    {
      "columns": [
        "_source"
      ],
      "sort": [
        "example-timestamp",
        "asc"
      ],
      "title": "Demo Import - Successful"
    }
  ]
};

function getObjects(name, data) {
  for(var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
    if(name.title == data.data[i].title) {
      var response = {
        "title": data.data[i].title,
        "sort": data.data[i].sort[0],
        "direction": data.data[i].sort[1],
        "columns": data.data[i].columns
      };
      return response;
    }
  }
}

var matchedObject = getObjects(match_title, objects);
console.log(matchedObject);
```

Comment: Okay, so that's how you check the index of a nested object. using data.data[i] instead of data[i]. Good to know. 

Thanks for your help! Have a great day.

Comment: in function scope `data` is alias for `objects`, calling `data.data` same as `objects.data`

Answer (score 1):

First, your `objects` JSON is invalid because you are trying to set `objects` to a property that stores an array, but you didn't wrap the object with `{` and `}`. You could just set the variable to a JSON array and then you don't need the property at all (and that's what I'm showing in my answer below).

The `Array.filter()` method can do this for you without explicit loops.

See below for corrections.

```js
var match_title = { title: "Demo Import - Successful" };

var data = `[
    {
        "columns": [ "_source" ], 
        "sort": [ "example-timestamp", "asc" ],
        "title": "Demo Import - Authorization Failure"
    },
    {
        "columns": [ "m-Form", "_type", "m-Identity" ],
        "sort": [ "_type", "asc" ],
        "title": "Demo Import - Timed Out"
    },
    {
        "columns": [ "_source" ],
        "sort": [ "example-timestamp", "asc" ],
        "title": "Demo Import - Successful"
    }
]`;

// New object will be stored here
var result = null;

function getObjects(name, data) {

  // parse the JSON into an array and filter the array based on input
  var match = JSON.parse(data).filter(function (entry) {

   // Just check if the item being enumerated has the value you seek
   if (entry.title === name){ 
      // Add the new property and set the placeholder object to the result
      entry.direction = entry.sort[1];
      entry.sort.pop();  // Remove sort direction from property array
      result = entry;
   }
  });
};

// Invoke the function
getObjects(match_title.title, data);

// Get the entire matched object:
console.log(result);

// Or, just individual properties of it:
console.log(result.columns);
console.log(result.sort);
console.log(result.title);
console.log(result.direction);
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `filter` in this code? It's just doing the work that `forEach` would do.

Comment: That is a lot simpler, but how can we use that same technique while manipulating the "sort" field to only contain the value "example-timestamp" instead of the array containing the direction, too?

Or should I just keep it as is, and when I want to use the sort field for my actual query, just call sort[0]?

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb Yes, but `forEach()` is a somewhat generic looping method. There are several others that are more specific (`map`, `some`, `reduce`, `filter`, `every`, etc.). `forEach` could be used instead of any of these, but the more specific ones tend to make the logic simpler in many cases or provided better semantics.

Comment: @JoeyMarinello Updated answer to do just that with `Array.pop()`, which removes the last element in an array.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! So if I want to now access those properties to use elsewhere, do I call "matchedObejct.title, matchedObject.columns, etc"?

Comment: @JoeyMarinello The way I have the answer set up is that the final object is stored in a variable (`result`) that has a higher scope than the function, so outside of the function you would just use `result.columns`, `result.sort`, `result.title` and `result.direction`. I'll update answer to show that.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is, filter doesn't seem to be the right method in your example. You don't filter anything. `match` would be empty.