# How to filter JSON data using Typescript / Javascript / Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have json data like this

```
data :[
{taskname:'chennai',    id:'maa' }
{taskname:'mumbai',     id:'bom' }
{taskname:'delhi',      id:'del' }
....
....
....
{taskname:'salem',      id:'che'}
{taskname:'bengaluru',  id:'blr'}
{taskname:'chavvapet',  id:'chv'}
}]
```

now i need to filter this data and return matching values (just like autocomplete). For example when i get value **CH** , first i need to check on **ID** and then on **taskname**. so the return value should be like this.
must order ID matching top and then taksname matching.

```
{taskname:'salem',      id:'che'}
{taskname:'chavvapet',  id:'chv'}
{taskname:'chennai',    id:'maa'}
```

Incase if i get value CHE, then i need to return value like this

```
{taskname:'salem',      id:'che'  }
{taskname:'chennai',    id:'maa'  }
```

Could someone please tell me how to do filter using typescript ?

[Tried few of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720988/how-to-filter-json-data-in-javascript-or-jquery), but no luck.

Comment: what you tried before ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code

```js
const data = [
{taskname:'chennai',  id:'maa',status:'Submitted'},
{taskname:'mumbai',   id:'bom',status:'Resolved'},
{taskname:'delhi',    id:'del',status:'Submitted'},
{taskname:'salem',    id:'che',status:'In Progress'},
{taskname:'bengaluru',id:'blr',status:'Resolved'},
{taskname:'chavvapet',id:'chv',status:'Submitted'}
];

function filterByString(data, s) {
   return data.filter(e => e.id.includes(s) || e.taskname.includes(s))
       .sort((a,b) => a.id.includes(s) && !b.id.includes(s) ? -1 : b.id.includes(s) && !a.id.includes(s) ? 1 :0);
}

console.log(filterByString(data, "ch"));
```

Comment: Its works fine in JS, but if i run same code type script it returns only one value instead all matching. Any idea ?

Comment: Seems like [Array.prototype.includes is missing in typescript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2340). Try to replace it with `indexOf(s) >= 0`