# (scrapy) HTTP GET response different from what's being displayed on browser

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to web scraping and scrapy.

I am trying to scrape items from a website by parsing the GET response which is in json.

However, I am noticing that instead of having just the 90 or so elements that are shown on the website, the raw json response contains 140 + elements.

Just by inspecting the json array, there doesn't seem to be any difference between items that do end up getting displayed in the browser vs those that don't.

Is it possible for me to capture with scrapy the filtered array of items instead of the raw information?

---

So I've realized that when the website loads, it makes 1 request for product details and 1 for stock availability. By cross-checking those responses, I realized that only those products with items available are displayed.

Now my questions is, can these 2 requests be handled in one scrapy spider class?

Comment: show an example?

Comment: Follow url it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720988/how-to-filter-json-data-in-javascript-or-jquery.

Comment: @Ol'Reliable: This is the website I'm interested in scraping https://www.zarahome.com/kr/bedroom/%EC%9D%B4%EB%B6%88-%EC%BB%A4%EB%B2%84-c1020116858.html (which shows 119 items--not 90 or so, my bad). 

I could scrape the <noscript> tag at the top, but I would like more information like product description, so I'm trying to scrape the request URL instead, which is this: https://www.zarahome.com/itxrest/2/catalog/store/85009966/80290010/category/1020116858/product?languageId=-9&appId=1

But both the <noscript> and json response show more items than what appears on the website.

Comment: @SKJ: thanks, but I'm not trying to extract/filter out data from the json array (yet), but trying to understand why the number of elements in the array are different from those shown on the browser

Comment: @hsy because your browser has java script engine in it and it will display code or nods generated by js as well . http get will only return you html nodes and tags . you should use requests instead . It will give you full webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend scraping all the items, and then filtering them in a [custom pipeline](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#writing-your-own-item-pipeline).

You would simply get the stock data in `open_spider()`, and filter out the items you don't need in `process_item()`.