# Creating an array out of a specific JSON Key-Value Pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Let's say I have a JSON array like this

```
[{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A4298","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A2222","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41Awww33","website":"yahoo"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A424448","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429rr8","website":"ebay"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ff8","website":"ebay"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ss8","website":"rediff"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429sg8","website":"yahoo"}]
```

I want to get an array of all the `name`s that have the `website` value equal to `google`.

Firstly, to filter the JSON array to contain only entries where the `website` is `google`, I have this:

```
var data_filter = data.filter( element => element.website =="google");
console.log(data_filter);
```

which gives the following result:

```
[{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A4298","website":"google"},
    {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A2222","website":"google"},
    {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A424448","website":"google"}]
```

What do I need to do next to get the `name` in a separate array. I tried doing this:

```
let new_array = [];
  new_array.push(data_filter.body.name)
```

which gives me an undefined error for `name`. I also tried:

```
new_array.push(data_filter.name)
  new_array.push(data_filter.body[0].name)
```

But none of the approaches work. What am I missing here?

FYI - JSON data and Filter approach is mentioned in this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720988/how-to-filter-json-data-in-javascript-or-jquery) - credits to the OP and answers.

Comment: `I have a JSON` Do you have something in JSON or an object? They're pretty different things

Comment: Your filter line won't work. You're assigning to every `element.website` with something truthy, so all items will pass the filter test.

Comment: What do you expect `data_filter.body` to be? You just logged `data_filter` as an array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use double equals sign to compare `==` instead of single `=`. When it’s single, you *change* (assign) `element.website` to `"google"`. The result of that expression is the value you set, which is `"google"` and it is a truthy value and therefore all elements pass the test of `filter()`.

```js
var data = [{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A4298","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A2222","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41Awww33","website":"yahoo"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A424448","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429rr8","website":"ebay"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ff8","website":"ebay"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ss8","website":"rediff"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429sg8","website":"yahoo"}];

var data_filter = data.filter( element => element.website == "google");

var names = data_filter.map(function (elem) {
  return elem.name;
});
console.log(names);
```

To get the names after you’ve filtered the results, use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Your code didn’t work because you try to access a property `body` of the filtered results. The filtered results consist of an array of your original results, but only the entries that pass the test. Since your original entries don’t have a `body` property, the filtered results won’t have it either. And also, you tried `data_filter.body` which will never exist because `data_filter` will always be an Array and arrays don’t have a `body` property.

Read more about `filter()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: Thanks for the link on filter method. I also found another helpful link here https://medium.com/@joomiguelcunha/learn-map-filter-and-reduce-in-javascript-ea59009593c4

Answer (score 4):

You can use `map` method in combination with `filter` and pass **callback** provided functions for each of them.

```js
let data = [{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A4298","website":"google"}, {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A2222","website":"google"}, {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41Awww33","website":"yahoo"}, {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A424448","website":"google"}, {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429rr8","website":"ebay"}, {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ff8","website":"ebay"}, {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ss8","website":"rediff"}, {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429sg8","website":"yahoo"}]

names = data.filter(function(item){
     return item.website == 'google';
}).map(function(item){
     return item.name;
});
console.log(names)
```

Another approach is to use `arrow` functions and **destructure** the arguments.

```js
let data = [{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A4298","website":"google"}, {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A2222","website":"google"}, {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41Awww33","website":"yahoo"}, {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A424448","website":"google"}, {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429rr8","website":"ebay"}, {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ff8","website":"ebay"}, {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ss8","website":"rediff"}, {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429sg8","website":"yahoo"}]

names = data.filter(({website}) => website == 'google').map(({name}) => name);
console.log(names)
```

Comment: Thanks for both the approaches. Both return same results. What's the difference though?

Comment: @demouser123, in the second one I used arrow functions which are features of `ES6`.

Comment: @demouser123, don't forget to accept and answer in order to help other people.

Comment: I don't understand why you used destructuring here. Do you find it easier to read than just `data.filter(d => d.website == 'google').map(d => d.name)` ?

Answer (score 4):

Use `map` after `filter` (also correct `=` with `===` )

```
var data_filter = data.filter( element => element.website === "google").map( s => s.name );
```

Or if you don't want to iterate twice, use `reduce`

```
data.reduce( (a, c) => {
   c.website === "google" ? a.push( c.name ) : "";
   return a; //return accumulator
} , []); //initialize accumulator
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce` to push to another array based on a condition:

```js
const data = [{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A4298","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A2222","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41Awww33","website":"yahoo"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A424448","website":"google"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429rr8","website":"ebay"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ff8","website":"ebay"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ss8","website":"rediff"},
{"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429sg8","website":"yahoo"}];
const nameArr = data.reduce((nameArr, { name, website }) => {
  if (website === 'google') nameArr.push(name);
  return nameArr;
}, []);
console.log(nameArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply map over the object array and IF item.website === 'google', push item.name into an array. See the working solution below...

```js
let theJSON = [
  {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A4298","website":"google"},
  {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A2222","website":"google"},
  {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41Awww33","website":"yahoo"},
  {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A424448","website":"google"},
  {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429rr8","website":"ebay"},
  {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ff8","website":"ebay"},
  {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429ss8","website":"rediff"},
  {"name":"Lenovo Thinkpad 41A429sg8","website":"yahoo"}
]

let nameArray = []

theJSON.map((item) => {
  if (item.website === 'google') {
    nameArray.push(item.name)
  }
})

console.log(nameArray)
```