# How to filter with console.log JSON?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, programmers-notepad

I need to filter in the console.log the data that I get from the json  that I show in the image. How could I do it?

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFFsy.png)

This is my .JSON

```
[
  {
    "category": "FORMULARIOS",
    "items": [
      {
        "label": "Botones",
        "url": "ui-botones"
      },
      {
        "label": "Inputs",
        "url": "ui-inputs"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "CORREOS",
    "items": [
      {
        "label": "Facturas",
        "url": "ui-facturas"
      },
      {
        "label": "Movimientos",
        "url": "ui-movimientos"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "ALERTAS",
    "items": [
      {
        "label": "Toast",
        "url": "ui-toast"
      },
      {
        "label": "Toolips",
        "url": "ui-toolips"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Please provide more details man! The input and the expected result.

Comment: No need, man. I mean you filter by category name or by label....and what is the result you wanna get such as the label or url....

Comment: I want to filter by category and I want to get the label as a result

Comment: You may want to read [ask].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter JSON Data in JavaScript or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720988/how-to-filter-json-data-in-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
var yourJSON ="......";
var newData = filterData('CORREOS');

function filterData(catalogyName) {
    return yourJSON.filter(object => {
        return object['category'] == catalogyName;
    });
}

console.log(newData);
```